# What is Kikuhiko's sexual orientation?

Tags: descending-stories

After the first season I was wondering about it. He even has some relationships with females but doesn't seem to exactly be interested.

Due to his complex relationship with Miyokichi and Sukeroku, things get a bit blurry (and even more so after I find out the author is experienced with the BL genre).

And even after the last episode in the 2nd season:

> where we get the possibility that he's still engaging sexually with young females

I still have this doubt: is Bon heterosexual, bisexual, homosexual, or asexual?

Comment: This might come across as haughty - it isn't meant to - but why does this matter?

Comment: @Makoto, don't matter. I'm just curious as fan and artist.